# Fake API Automation: Assertion is not working

Tags: java, api, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am testing a fake API https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

These are the following tasks:

- Get a random user (userID), print out its email address to console.
- Using this userID, get this user’s associated posts and verify they contain a valid Post IDs (an Integer between 1 and 100).
- Do a post using the same userID with a non-empty title and body, verify the correct response is returned (since this is a mock API, it might not return Response code 200, so check the documentation).

Below is the code I have written:

```
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

public class JsonPlaceHolder {
    @Test
    public void getUserId() {
        Response response = given().when().get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?id=2")
                .then().assertThat().statusCode(200).extract().response();
        String responseInString = response.asString();
        System.out.println(responseInString);

        // get the user email address from the response
        JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(responseInString);
        String emailAddress = jsonPath.getString("email");
        System.out.println(emailAddress);
    }

    @Test
    public void userPost() {
        Response response = given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).when().get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=2")
                .then().assertThat().statusCode(200).extract().response();
        String responseInString = response.asString();
        System.out.println(responseInString);

        // Using the userID, get the user’s associated posts and
        JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(responseInString);
        String userPosts = jsonPath.getString("title");
        System.out.println(userPosts);

        // verify the Posts contain valid Post IDs (an Integer between 1 and 100).
        String postId = response.asString();
        System.out.println(postId);
        **response.then().assertThat().body("id", allOf(greaterThanOrEqualTo(1), lessThanOrEqualTo(100)));**
    }
}
```

This is the Assertion error I am getting below: **Please suggest some solution. Thanks**

java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path id doesn't match.
Expected: (a value equal to or greater than <1> and a value less than or equal to <100>)
  Actual: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

Comment: What are you exactly asking? Did you look at what your result is that you're checking? Looks like a list of integers.

Comment: I am getting the error on this very line.

response.then().assertThat().body("id", allOf(greaterThanOrEqualTo(1), lessThanOrEqualTo(100)));

Answer (score 1):

Your main mistake is that the id field in the body actually is an array and not a single value, therefore the `allOf` matcher is applied to the array rather than to each individual value and resulting in an error.

Basically, you need to chain a [everyItem](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.1/org/hamcrest/core/Every.html#everyItem-org.hamcrest.Matcher-) matcher before:

```
response.then().assertThat().body("id", everyItem(allOf(greaterThanOrEqualTo(1), lessThanOrEqualTo(100))));
```

Comment: Thanks, @maio290. I have done the following and the error is gone.

response.then().assertThat().body("id", everyItem(greaterThanOrEqualTo(1)));
response.then().assertThat().body("id", everyItem(lessThanOrEqualTo(100)));

any other short way to do this assertion?

Comment: You can still use the allOf matcher?